# Using Regex vs includes() method with Switch Statment

Tags: javascript, regex

I making an AJAX request to OpenWeatherMap.org API to get the local weather forecast (temp, city, and weather description). I am assigning the weather description to a variable "weatherDescription". I am using a switch statement to check if "weatherDescription" has "clouds" for example in the description and if it does changing the icon of an image of a element within the DOM to a "cloudy" icon image.

The code below works in Chrome but unfortunately the .includes() method does not work in other browsers (Safari, IE, Opera etc).

```
function SwitchIcons() {
        switch (true) {
          case (weatherDescription.includes('clear')):
            icon.className = "";
            icon.classList.add("wi", "wi-day-sunny");
            break;
          case (weatherDescription.includes('rain')):
            icon.className = "";
            icon.classList.add("wi", "wi-day-rain");
        }
      }
      SwitchIcons();
```

So, I am now testing "weatherDescription" against a regExp but the condition always returns true for the first case (example below) :

```
var myRegExp = /sun|rain|sleet/ig; 
switch (true) {
              case myRegExp.test(weatherDescription)):
                icon.className = "";
                icon.classList.add("wi", "wi-day-sunny");
                break;
case myRegExp.test(weatherDescription)):
icon.className = "";
icon.classList.add("wi", "wi-day-rain");
}
```

Is it possible to accomplish the same results I was receiving using .includes() method with regEx or is there a better way of accomplishing this goal?

Comment: Is it `var myRegExp = /sun|rain|sleet\ig;` or `var myRegExp = /sun|rain|sleet/ig;` in your code? and note you should not use `test()` with `g`.

Comment: You could use the RegExp constructor instead : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: oops typo  it's myRegExp = /sun|rain|sleet/ig;

Comment: And what about my second remark? Try removing `g` and using `var myRegExp = /sun|rain|sleet/i;`.

Comment: @stribizhev I have tried removing the g and using var myRegExp = /sun|rain|sleet/i; If the RegExp is testing for all the strings how will it differentiate the first case from the second case?  With Includes() method I was testing each case against a specific string.

Comment: Please check the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `g` modifier. The second call to `test` will try to match *starting from the previous match*, not at the beginning of the string. Regular expression objects in JavaScript have state, which matters when you use `g` with `test`, `exec`, and similar.

Here's a simpler example demonstrating the problem:

```js
var rex;
rex = /test/g;
snippet.log(rex.test("test")); // true
snippet.log(rex.test("test")); // false
// vs.
rex = /test/;
snippet.log(rex.test("test")); // true
snippet.log(rex.test("test")); // true
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```